# Only copy valid elements and attributes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am trying to use XSLT to convert one XML document to another XML document. Is it possible to specify in the stylesheet that I only want to copy elements/attributes that are 'valid'? By valid I mean that they exist in the destination schema.

For example, given source.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:more_emotion="http://example.org/more_emotion"
    targetNamespace="http://example.org/more_emotion"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Emotion" type="more_emotion:imComplex"/>
    <xs:complexType name="imComplex">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Joy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Anger" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Confusion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And destination.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://example.org/emotion"
    xmlns:emotion="http://example.org/emotion"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Emotion" type="emotion:imComplex"/>
    <xs:complexType name="imComplex">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Joy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And xml document that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<more_emotion:Emotion xmlns:more_emotion="http://example.org/more_emotion">
    <more_emotion:Joy>Hooray!</more_emotion:Joy>
    <more_emotion:Anger>Grrr</more_emotion:Anger>
    <more_emotion:Confusion>Huh?</more_emotion:Confusion>
</more_emotion:Emotion>
```

Is it possible use XSLT to transform the document to the following **without** having to name the specific elements/attributes to copy or exclude?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<more_emotion:Emotion xmlns:more_emotion="http://example.org/more_emotion">
    <more_emotion:Joy>Hooray!</more_emotion:Joy>
</more_emotion:Emotion>
```

Thinking about it in pseudo-code I need something like

```
for each element or attribute in document
    if element or attribute exists in destination schema
        copy element or attribute to destination document
    else
        discard element or attribute
```

The part I don't know how to do (or if it's possible in XSLT) is `if element or attribute exists in destination schema`.

Comment: Please note: I realize I could simply write XSLT that would only copy the `Joy` element. Alternatively, I could have XSLT that would copy everything except `Anger` and `Confusion`. However, I am not asking how to do that. My real scenario is much more complicated and I have simplified it here to the simplest case I could think of.

Comment: There are tools like Altova's MapForce which can do XSD to XSD mappings, but even then you are going to need to provide some manual intervention and it probably won't be 100% if its more than a trivial mapping. Also the namespace of your output XML doesn't map the desired namespace of the output XSD, so you might want to check that too.

Comment: Yes the namespaces are different. My XSLT will need to account for this as well but that is a separate issue that I have solved already. 95% of the two schemas are identical (with exception of namespace changing); I'm trying to come up with a plan for that other 5%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How complex do you want this? Are you worried about checking the position of elements in the hierarchy to see if that corresponds to what is specified in the schema? Or is it really just a case of checking the element name exists somewhere?

If you do want to keep it "simple" and check the element name is specified somewhere in the schema, you could first start off by using the XSLT identity transform

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This copies all nodes, and attributes, as-is, so you only need to write templates for things you want to change. Or in your case, for things you don't want to copy.

Using the "document" function you could have a template that looks up to see there are not any elements in the schema document with the same name, and simply ignore the element.

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(local-name() = document('destination.xsd')//xs:element/@name)]" />
```

You could write a similar ones for attributes. Try this XSLT for a start

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[not(local-name() = document('destination.xsd')//xs:element/@name)]" />

   <xsl:template match="@*[not(local-name() = document('destination.xsd')//xs:attribute/@name)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following:

```
<more_emotion:Emotion xmlns:more_emotion="http://example.org/more_emotion">
   <more_emotion:Joy>Hooray!</more_emotion:Joy>
</more_emotion:Emotion>
```

Note that, if you wanted to carry on processing the children of a 'discarded' element, to see if they match, change the first template to this

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(local-name() = document('destination.xsd')//xs:element/@name)]">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: For the more complex mappings (where an element changes names or moves in the hierarchy) I believe I will need to have specific templates to handle those scenarios. I think this simple checking will be sufficient to cover the other scenarios where elements have been added in the source xsd that have no equivalent in the destination xsd.

Comment: I was able to test this and it works exactly as you describe. Thanks.